# Multilevel Approval Workflow Using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I need to create a multilevel Approval Workflow for following scenario:

1. Workflow starts once item is created employee (Say in a ProductList) for certain Amount.
2. Manager Approves the workflow.
3. If Amount is < $5000, email goes to Employee as approved.
4. If Amount is > $5000, further approval is required. Item goes for further approval to VP and then CEO.

I am getting many examples on workflow, most of the examples are sending just an email based on condition. I need sending for further approval based on condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a list with the following columns
   a.  Product Name (Text box)
   b.  Price(Text box)
   c.  Mgr approval (choice)
   d.  Final approval(Choice)
2. Hide column c & d using JavaScript when user enter the value
3. a Create a workflow in item created for  sending mail to manager
4. Show the column c using JavaScript or the manager
5. Create another workflow for send mail to final approval on item edited event after checking following conditions
   a.  Amount >5000 
   b.  Mgrapproval (c) status is approved
6. Show the column d using JavaScript for the final approval

You can use simple JavaScript if the mgrapprover and final approver does not change. If these values are dynamic it is better to create a webpart for generating JavaScript by checking the login user group.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Create a list with your approval items in it
2. Create an approval request as you have done
3. Check whether the amount >= 5000
4. If it is ask for approval from the VP and CEO (follow the same steps as you do for step 1 but this time using VP and CEO prefixes for your variables and collection tasks).

If possible, I'd also reference external lists for the amount to check at, and for the VP and CEO names - so that you dont have to redeploy the workflows when the amount changes or the VP/CEO change.

Theres a good write up of a [similar multiple approval SP workflow scenario here](http://cycogeek.fiesta25.com/blogs/cycogeek/page/Create-Custom-Approval-Workflow-with-SharePoint-Designer.aspx)

As an Aside, you might not want to send the emails with the task url, I'd suggest coding the actual edit page urls into the email so that users (i.e. Managers, VP and CEO) dont have to view the task, then click edit item, then approve, by viewing the Edit screen you can get the url and input your Workflow TaskItemID into the url directly which will give the end user a better overall experience.  Only one button click to approve/reject instead of multiple clicks to just get to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I did this kind of thing by having a workflow like yours on the first list and when a certain condition is fullfilled(like >5000$), I move the item in another list where another workflow process it for approval like you need to. It may seem like your multiplicating workflow, but I usually prefer to have more pretty simple workflow than one workflow that does a lot of things.